# Create interdependent quiz questions with mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, architecture, backend

I am creating a quiz question where the **sub questions depend on the answer to the main question**.

#### Example

Question 1 - What is your post?
A) Manager
B) Developer
C) Tester

Based on question 1's answer we have to ask next question
Question 2.

if A) => What project are you leading?
Based on question 2's answer we have to ask next question

if B) => Who do you report to?
Based on question 2's answer we have to ask next question

if C) => What software do you use for testing?
Based on question 2's answer we have to ask next question

Can you help me to decide how I can implement this dynamically with SQL database and how I can show it on frontend?

Comment: It seems that you need in common one-to-many or many-to-many tables reference which refers (question's answer) to (next question).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a sort of decision tree structure within SQL. I'll note right away that you will need to be very careful not to create an infinite loop with this.

### Data Structure

Sample Diagram ([eraser](https://www.tryeraser.com)) depicting a simple database structure for this:

[image]

> Note: the right design depends on your use case.

1. Add a quiz
2. Add your questions to the `Question` table
3. Add the possible answers to each question in the Answer table. A question can have multiple possible answers.
4. Specify the decision tree using the `NextQuestion` table. Use a combination of the `QuizID` and `AnswerID` to determine what the `NextQuestionID` should be.

To help avoid an infinite loop, a unique constraint can be placed on the `NextQuestion` table. It won't prevent it though. Make sure there's validation logic in place to ensure an infinite loop is detected and stopped before committing the tree when creating the Quiz.

The front-end could be in two parts: The Quiz, and The Quiz Setup

### The Quiz Setup

This provides a UI to create a new quiz. Depending on your use case, you may need to extend the database for back-office support which may impact The Quiz Setup.

> Note: you could fill the database manually but this removes the
> ability to add validation.

### The Quiz

Assuming the quiz is a single question at a time (because the answer matters) there needs to be a way to indicate which question should be asked first. This could be handled by adding another column to the `Quiz` to indicate the root question id.

1. You need the quiz id and the first question id
2. Display the quiz name and the first question text
3. Display the possible answers from the `Answer` table based on the `QuestionID`
4. On Answer-submit, the `QuizID` and `AnswerID` will indicate the next `Question` via the `NextQuestionID`.

> Note: you shouldn't need the current question id. It can be retrieved via
> the `Answer` if needed.

5. Repeat #2-#4 until there are no more questions to answer (for example: when there isn't a `NextQuestionID` specified for the current `QuizID` and `AnswerID` combination).

These steps can be supported by endpoints specified in a node.js web service.

**Other Considerations:**

- How the navigation happens between questions is impacted if a user is allowed to go back to a previous question.
- The data structure specified doesn't support all cases such as if a user can save their place and come back later.